# Getting "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: c#, web-services, azure, soap, tls1.2

I have some websites that some times fails on connecting to a 3rd party SOAP WS. It happen most when there a lot of requests to the 3rd party WS. So it not fails every time, only some times - and mostly when there is a lot of requests to the 3rd party ws.

It have been fixed on our on premises servers with IIS Crypto. All disabled checkbox was checked before.

But on Azure WebApp we cant controls theese settings - any idea what to do?

Heres is the code of the binding and more to the 3rd party soap ws:

```
        public static CustomBinding GetDefaultBinding()
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

        AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement securityElement = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement();

        securityElement.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12;

        securityElement.InitiatorTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.IssuerSerial, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never);
        securityElement.RecipientTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.IssuerSerial, SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never);
        securityElement.ProtectTokens = true;

        securityElement.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt;

        securityElement.RequireSignatureConfirmation = true;

        securityElement.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax;
        securityElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
        securityElement.IncludeTimestamp = true;
        securityElement.SetKeyDerivation(false);
        securityElement.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128Rsa15;
        securityElement.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SignedEncrypted.Add(new UserNameSecurityTokenParameters());
        securityElement.AllowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply = true;

        CustomBinding myBinding = new CustomBinding();
        myBinding.Elements.Add(securityElement);

        TextMessageEncodingBindingElement element = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11WSAddressing10, Encoding.UTF8);
        element.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
        element.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = int.MaxValue;
        element.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
        element.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue;
        element.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue;
        myBinding.Elements.Add(element);

        HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBindingElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
        httpsBindingElement.RequireClientCertificate = true;
        httpsBindingElement.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
        httpsBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
        httpsBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        httpsBindingElement.KeepAliveEnabled = false;
        httpsBindingElement.AllowCookies = false;

        myBinding.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement);

        myBinding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        myBinding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        myBinding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);

        return myBinding;
    }

        private void ConfigureClientCredentials(ClientCredentials cc)
    {
        if (cc == null) return;

        cc.UserName.UserName = Options.WebserviceUsername;
        cc.UserName.Password = Options.AuthPassword;

        cc.ClientCertificate.Certificate = Options.ClientCertificate;
        cc.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = Options.IbaCertificate;

        cc.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
    }

    private void ConfigureEndPoint(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
        endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomEndpointBehavior());

    }
```

[image: All disabled checkbox was checked before]

[image: All disabled checkbox was checked before]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd party SOAP WS was configured with wrong SSL/chipers on one server (load balancer setup), that caused the problems - so it was not an problem in my code.

Comment: That was quick - great. One final hint: I think you might want to read about Clean Code (for the great book by Robert Martin). Your code might profit from that.